# sql server, group by then count, 25 million rows per month, feasibility

Tags: sql-server

So.

We are doing some analytics in a scale I have no experience with. We have to extract some aggregate numbers and data from a whole bunch of server logs. (Estimated at 2gig a month total).

I'm estimating around 25 million rows to be inserted into the table per month. Relatively wide table, 10 columns of varchar(25).

Then we have to do a group by (string column) then count the unique values. We'll process month by month, then probably quarterly/yearly depending on feedback from business.

So. Worst case scenario

```
count(string_column) from table group by (string_column)
```

over 300 million rows (25 * 12).

Is sql server a viable solution? Viable, as in:

1. Computable. group by / count operation not taking more than 10 to 15 min.
2. Maintainable. Backup not taking more than 10 to 15 min.
3. Operable. As in inserting 2 million a row everyday into a 300 million row table with 5 indexed columns not taking ridiculously long.
4. Economical. Running on a virtual machine with 8 virtual core (whatever that means. they say it's 1:1 to physical) and 16 gig ram with the usual crappy disk IO. Is that enough? Would an optimised bare metal host be needed?

Those time I put in there really is just what I'm expecting (10 to 15min thing). To put it into context. We can run over night jobs. When we come in the next day and something goes wrong, backing up / restore db, recrunching the numbers in the next day has to happen in "timely fashion".

Apology for not being able to go into more details, but if someone who operated with those parameters can shed some light, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, just a P.S. I've used aws EMR to directly extract the numbers (25mil a month, and a few others). But the team would hear none of it. They work with SQL server, and that's what they going to do. Prepping the data into CSV format so it can be imported into the SQL server is already taking a team of 3 a whole day. (The scripting, SSIS design, db schema, etc etc etc). We haven't even got started analyzing. Just wondering if it's a sane consideration.

Comment: What you're asking for will barely make SQL Server break a sweat, assuming appropriate indexes. Depending on the size of your reports, 16GB of ram might not cut it, but 8vcpus is certainly adequate; if not overkill.

Comment: If you have a (reasonably) limited set of values, you could aggressively reduce the width of your column by converting at least the key columns into codes from a lookup table. Then, the indexed columns would be ints and both the table and indices would shrink by a factor of 8. With BULK inserts you can exceed 20k rows a second easily - performance should not be a problem.